# Making function single threaded and running in background

Tags: python

I am trying to implement **in-memory queue like Kafka using Python** using concepts like **re-entrant locks and threads.** I am new to Python threading.

I have a *consumer* which will *subscribe to the topic* and *read a message* from it. So far it's working fine but I have doubts related to threading.

I am trying to make the `consumerRunner` process single- threaded.
When checking the output I am seeing `MainThread` and `Thread-1`. If the function is single-threaded, should it not be displaying the message single time by the thread which is executing this function?
`Message2` and `Message4` has been consumed twice.
With the single thread they should be consumed only once. I know main Thread is the default Thread but is it correct to have msg printed twice? Sorry if I am asking silly question.

**Output:**

```
(py3_8) ninjakx@Kritis-MacBook-Pro kafka % python queueDemo.py
Msg: message1 has been published to topic: topic1
Msg: message2 has been published to topic: topic1
Msg: message3 has been published to topic: topic2
Msg: message4 has been published to topic: topic1
Msg: message1 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 0 with current thread: MainThread
Msg: message3 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 0 with current thread: MainThread
Msg: message2 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 1 with current thread: Thread-1
Msg: message2 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 1 with current thread: MainThread
Msg: message4 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 2 with current thread: Thread-1
Msg: message4 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 2 with current thread: MainThread
```

#### ConsumerImpl.py

```
import zope.interface
from ..interface.iConsumer import iConsumer
from collections import OrderedDict
from mediator.QueueMediatorImpl import QueueMediatorImpl

import threading 
from threading import Thread
import time
 
@zope.interface.implementer(iConsumer)
class ConsumerImpl:
    # will keep all the topic it has subscribed to and their offset

    def __init__(self, consumerName:str):
        self.__consumerName = consumerName
        self.__topicList = []
        self.__topicVsOffset = OrderedDict()
        self.__queueMediator = QueueMediatorImpl()
        self.threadInit()


    def threadInit(self):
        thread = Thread(target = self._consumerRunner)
        thread.start()
        # thread.join()
        # print("thread finished...exiting")        

    def __getConsumerName(self):
        return self.__consumerName

    def __getQueueMediator(self):
        return self.__queueMediator

    def __getSubscribedTopics(self)->list:
        return self.__topicList

    def __setTopicOffset(self, topicName:str, offset:int)->int:
        self.__topicVsOffset[topicName] = offset

    def __getTopicOffset(self, topicName:str)->int:
        return self.__topicVsOffset[topicName]

    def __addToTopicList(self, topicName:str)->None:
        self.__topicList.append(topicName)

    def _subToTopic(self, topicName:str):
        self.__addToTopicList(topicName)
        self.__topicVsOffset[topicName] = 0

    def __consumeMsg(self, msg:str, offset:int):
        print(f"Msg: {msg} has been consumed by consumer: {self.__getConsumerName()} at offset: {offset} with current thread: {threading.current_thread().name}\n")


    # pull based mechanism
    # running on single thread
    def _consumerRunner(self):
        while(True):
            for topicName in self.__getSubscribedTopics():
                curOffset = self.__getTopicOffset(topicName)
                qmd = self.__getQueueMediator()
                msg = qmd._readMsgIfPresent(topicName, curOffset)
                if msg is not None:
                    self.__consumeMsg(msg._getMessage(), curOffset)
                    curOffset += 1
                # update offset
                self.__setTopicOffset(topicName, curOffset)

            try:
                #sleep for 100 milliseconds
                #thread sleep
                # "sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored."
                time.sleep(0.1)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
```

#### QueueDemo.py

```
from service.QueueServiceImpl import QueueServiceImpl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queueService = QueueServiceImpl()
    producer1 = queueService._createProducer("producer1")
    producer2 = queueService._createProducer("producer2")
    producer3 = queueService._createProducer("producer3")
    producer4 = queueService._createProducer("producer4")

    consumer1 = queueService._createConsumer("consumer1")
    consumer2 = queueService._createConsumer("consumer2")
    consumer3 = queueService._createConsumer("consumer3")
    
    producer1._publishToTopic("topic1", "message1")
    producer1._publishToTopic("topic1", "message2")
    producer2._publishToTopic("topic2", "message3")
    producer1._publishToTopic("topic1", "message4")

    consumer1._subToTopic("topic1")
    consumer1._subToTopic("topic2")

    consumer1._consumerRunner()
```

Comment: Code is here:
https://github.com/ninjakx/LLD-kafka

Comment: Each call to `queueService._createConsumer` creates a new `ConsumerImpl` object, which starts another consumer thread.  So you will definitely have at least 4 threads running.

Comment: @TimRoberts so is this logically correct behaviour? sorry if it's a silly question to ask I just started practicing threads but the same code was in java so I implemented it in Python and locks. Since msg was printing twice so I am assuming  the same message might be processed twice :(

Comment: The whole point of a publish/subscribe pattern is that a published message is handled by ALL of the clients that have subscribed to that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a consumer object you are creating a new thread as part of startup:

```
class ConsumerImpl:
    ...
    def __init__(self, consumerName:str):
        ...
        self.threadInit()

    def threadInit(self):
        thread = Thread(target = self._consumerRunner)
        thread.start()
    ...
```

This will execute `_consumerRunner` on a new thread. This method spins forever with a `while True` loop. In the main of your application, you are then calling `_consumerRunner` directly.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    consumer1 = queueService._createConsumer("consumer1")
    ...
    consumer1._consumerRunner()
```

So now you have called `_consumerRunner` twice. Once directly in the main thread, and once when creating the consumer object in the constructor. This is why you're seeing the duplicate lines:

```
Msg: message2 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 1 with current thread: Thread-1
Msg: message2 has been consumed by consumer: consumer1 at offset: 1 with current thread: MainThread
```

So you should remove the direct call to `consumer1._consumerRunner()` from the main.

---

Some style notes:

- Python uses snake_case predominantly. You should update your methods accordingly (e.g. `_consumer_runner` vs `_consumerRunner`).
- You mark many value as private (in Python, the standard convention is to use a leading `_` in the name), however, you are accessing these methods and attributes from outside of the class. If you intend to use these methods external of the class which defines them, leave off the leading underscore, as these methods should be listed as your public contract.
- I would strongly avoid using dunder `__` method and attribute names. Nothing in Python is truly private, and if you follow standard conventions, you shouldn't be using anything marked private normally with a single underscore anyways. The dunder variables also have special logic which mangles the name external to the class, which can cause a lot of not-so-fun bugs. Only use them if you have MASSIVE classes, and need to strongly guarantee that two layers in your class hierarchy do not conflict on naming choices.
- The `zope.interface` package seems like overkill to me. There are many other ways to keep contracts in check, such as normal abstract classes (using the abc class), and by using static analysis tools such as mypy or pyright to ensure objects are used appropriately. This keeps heavy boilerplate libraries out of your code keeping things more terse.
- After you create your threads, you never keep track of them. For proper shutdown of the application you should add logic to collect them and ensure they are closed and joined. A `ThreadPoolExecutor`, or `ExitStack` could help with that.
- Get into the habit of using the `logging` module. It is a lot more flexible than calls to `print` and will provide a uniform look to your logging across the application.

Comment: can you tell me how to exactly use `ThreadPoolExecutor` in this example? 
Thanks for reviewing the code and listing out the area of improvement as well.

Comment: even after removing the `consumer1._consumerRunner()   ` from main I am getting msg twice sometimes.

Comment: @Pygirl for for ThreadPoolExecutor, there are some good [examples in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Apart from this, you need to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Its not possible for anyone to reproduce the issue as is. Try to boil your code down to the minimal set of functionality that can reproduce the issue. Also start investing in writing unit tests to help verify expected behavior.

Comment: full code is : github.com/ninjakx/LLD-kafka  I added consumer and main file only which is calling everything as this is related to consumer side. Tried to keep it minimal :( for reproducing full code has to be run.

Comment: I think you meant to directly add the msg to the queue. `producer1._publishToTopic` removing producer from main nd directly feeding the msg to queue so that above code  error can be reproduced as then there will be no dependency. That will require lot of changes to be made to create MCVE :(

Comment: Seems like logically this is where leading to double call of that print line but even after fixing by the above mentioned I still get the same. Though I can''t provide the MCVE because there are lot of modules present inside the other folder. Thanks for suggesting code changes as well and giving your precious time to look into my problem :)

Comment: @Pygirl the point of the MVCE is not to post your actual production code, but that you render it down enough that it can fit within a bite sized chunk and still reproduce the issue. One advantage of this approach, is that often times when you perform this exercise, the issue will present itself much more clearly as you have eliminated the other factors at play.

Comment: Start by eliminating unneeded boilerplate, cutting out classes where possible, and getting the least amount of lines possible to reproduce the issue.